# DI of a service used by many different ViewModels

Tags: .net, mvvm, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a ViewManager that I use to manage my Views. It is placed in the App.View namespace and implements an IViewManager interface, placed in the App.ViewModel library.

The problem is that this class is used by many ViewModels, because many of them need to show another View. So I need to ctor-inject the ViewManager in many ViewModels, but some of them need a Factory to be created, so my questions are:

- is this a normal issue or am I wrong with some aspects?
- should the new ViewModel receive the ViewManager from the ShellViewModel
  ex: `var newVM = ViewModelFactory.Create(this.ViewManager, ...)`
  (where "this" is the ShellViewModel)
  or from the factory?
  ex: `var newVM = ViewModelFactory.Create(...)`
  (that implies the ViewManager is injected into the Factory by the container)?

Thank you all for your help!

**EDIT**

```cs
namespace BM.ViewModel
{
    public interface IViewManager
    {
        void Register<TViewInterface, TViewImplementation>(bool reset = false)
            where TViewInterface : IView
            where TViewImplementation : TViewInterface;

        void Unregister<TView>()
            where TView : IView;

        void UnregisterAll();

        TView GetView<TView>(BaseViewModel viewModel)
            where TView : IView;

        IEnumerable<IView> GetViews(BaseViewModel viewModel);

        IEnumerable<IView> GetAllViews();

        void CloseViews<TView>()
            where TView : IView;

        void CloseViews(BaseViewModel viewModel);


        void CloseAllViews();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems fine, you are injecting dependencies and using factories, these are good practices.

Regarding `ViewManager` instance, if ViewManager is singleton - it does not matter how to access it - using a factory or any other reference to ViewManager must return the same instance. And I do not see why you should keep many instances of ViewManager, *but it depends* on your specific application design. So please share `IViewManager` interface declaration and give some comments for each method so it will be clear whether `IViewManager` should be a singleton or not.

Some points to concern

- Is `ViewManager` stateless?
- Is there any functionality which obligates ViewManager to keep references to all View instancess?

Comment: hi sll, thank you for your reply. Well, I'm a student and I'm trying to learn MVVM. So any tip is very welcome! =) Anyway, I'll edit the main post with the IViewManager interface I created. I'm not using many instances of it, but it's the same that has to be passed to almost every ViewModel. My doubt is about if it's better to inject it in the factory or pass it from the ShellViewModel as a parameter to the factory.Create() function.
Thank you for you patience!!

P.S. the class is not a singleton, should I add an IViewManager type property to the interface and access the instance through it?

Comment: It seem like a [Repiository](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) pattern implementation. ([C# example](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/)). At least you can split this interface ([ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)) into the two, one of them will be IViewRepository with all methods except 3 `CloseViews()` methods and an other one something like `IViewCloser` (sorry for bad name can't find appropriate one).

Comment: Thank you! I'll now take a look at what you linked. Anyway, in your opinion, is this a good solution, are there any better, has it any drawbacks? Thank you again!

Comment: Just the question, who should give the ViewManager instance to the new ViewModel? The Factory class (IoCC -> Factory -> newVM) or the ShellViewModel? (IoCC -> ShellViewModel -> newVM)?